# javascript show geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, html-framework-7

im building a web mobile friendly web application with framework 7 which must show to the user his location...

I use this code:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error

the js code is located in my js file at the bottom

but each time i run it i get this error:

Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

any clues why?

Comment: Where is your code? The W3schools code works fine as long as you enable location services.

Comment: @Developer i used that code but im getting an error

Comment: I just answered your question. See below :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran it in Firefox 45.0.2 and it works fine. You need to make sure share location is enabled and not blocked by default. If one browser doesn't work, try it in another, or reset your location services.

Comment: So if i run it through a different browser (im using chrome) will it fix the "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" error? The location services are fine

Comment: I assume so because it works just fine for me. Same code as you. If this answer helps, please upvote it :)

Comment: and I still getting an error... "TypeError: x is null" in firefox

Comment: Then it may be an issue with framework 7. If it works regularly in the browser, but not framework 7, then it is probably a bug in framework 7. Remember, if my answer was helpful, please upvote it :)

Comment: Well i had to delete that code coz it wasnt working on f7